# JSON - Backslashes in Network Path

Tags: json

I have a PHP api which returns this JSON:

```
{
    "recrutee": {
        "recrutee_nom": "Mustermann",
        "recrutee_statut": "Extern",
        "recrutee_id_iam": "APP764",
        "recrutee_debut_de_contrat": "2018-08-30",
        "recrutee_fin_de_contrat": "2018-11-29",
        "recrutee_prenom": "Max"
    },
    "responsable": {
        "responsable_nom": "Musterman",
        "responsable_prenom": "Marc",
        "responsable_tel": "66666666",
        "responsable_service": "It",
        "responsable_email": "example@example.com"
    },
    "acces_reseau": [{
        "path": "\\Some\Network\Path"
    }],
    "option_pc": [
        {
            "autre": "Nfc Reader"
        }, {
            "option": "internet"
        }, {
            "option": "lecteurluxtrust"
        }, {
            "option": "scanner"
        }, {
            "option": "imprimante"
        }, {
            "option": "ecransupplementaire"
        }, {
            "option": "lectuercodebarres"
        }
    ],
    "demande_id": "5b54588d00772",
    "lieu": "Luxembourg City"
}
```

The problem is with the network path is it needs to look like this:

```
\\\\Some\\Network\\Path
```

Since backslashes are used as an escape character the network path in my original json is incorrect.

Is there any programatically (not manual) way to get this result:

```
\\\\Some\\Network\\Path
```

Comment: *"Is there any programatically (not manual) way to get this result:"* Build up the structure in an object graph, and use `json_encode` to create the JSON. Building it by hand results in these kinds of simple errors.

Comment: Ok indeed that was the mistake, thank you very much.